# Appending the values list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have dictionary, which contains different list.

I want toc combine data in different dictionary appending values of similar keys in it.

```
{'mental_issue': ['stress', 'live in fear', 'stomach curl', 'wracked by stress', 'chest tighten']}
{'sexual_abuse': ['stalking'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse', 'pica']}
{}
{'verbal_abuse': ['in the face'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse']}
{}
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']}
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']}
{'mental_abuse': ['name call'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse']}
{}
{'mental_issue': ['broken jaw', 'abuse', 'heart broken']}
{'mental_issue': ['live in fear']}
{'mental_issue': ['abuse', 'trauma']}
{'mental_issue': ['nightmares', 'abuse', 'panic attack']}
{'mental_issue': ['stress']}
{'mental_issue': ['severe']}
{'mental_issue': ['nightmares', 'bad emotional state']}
{'sexual_abuse': ['rape'], 'mental_issue': ['stress', 'paranoia']}
{'mental_issue': ['fracturing both my', 'both my knees']}
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']}
{'sexual_abuse': ['rape'], 'verbal_abuse': ['kicking'], 'mental_issue': ['nightmares']}
```

I want to combine values of all issues like `mental_abuse`  should have all mental aboses from all dictionary.

I wrote this logic -

```
sexual_abuse_list = []
d = {'sexual_abuse': ['rape'], 'verbal_abuse': ['kicking'], 'mental_issue': ['nightmares']}
if 'sexual_abuse' in d:
    for item in d['sexual_abuse']:
            sexual_abuse_list.append(item)
```

Is this correct logic? or any better logic can be written?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict


lst = [{'mental_issue': ['stress', 'live in fear', 'stomach curl', 'wracked by stress', 'chest tighten']},
{'sexual_abuse': ['stalking'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse', 'pica']},
{},
{'verbal_abuse': ['in the face'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse']},
{},
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']},
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']},
{'mental_abuse': ['name call'], 'mental_issue': ['abuse']},
{},
{'mental_issue': ['broken jaw', 'abuse', 'heart broken']},
{'mental_issue': ['live in fear']},
{'mental_issue': ['abuse', 'trauma']},
{'mental_issue': ['nightmares', 'abuse', 'panic attack']},
{'mental_issue': ['stress']},
{'mental_issue': ['severe']},
{'mental_issue': ['nightmares', 'bad emotional state']},
{'sexual_abuse': ['rape'], 'mental_issue': ['stress', 'paranoia']},
{'mental_issue': ['fracturing both my', 'both my knees']},
{'mental_issue': ['abuse']},
{'sexual_abuse': ['rape'], 'verbal_abuse': ['kicking'], 'mental_issue': ['nightmares']}]

d = defaultdict(list)

for i in lst:
    for k, v in i.items():
        d[k].extend(v)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'sexual_abuse': ['stalking', 'rape', 'rape'], 'verbal_abuse': ['in the face', 'kicking'], 'mental_abuse': ['name call'], 'mental_issue': ['stress', 'live in fear', 'stomach curl', 'wracked by stress', 'chest tighten', 'abuse', 'pica', 'abuse', 'abuse', 'abuse', 'abuse', 'broken jaw', 'abuse', 'heart broken', 'live in fear', 'abuse', 'trauma', 'nightmares', 'abuse', 'panic attack', 'stress', 'severe', 'nightmares', 'bad emotional state', 'stress', 'paranoia', 'fracturing both my', 'both my knees', 'abuse', 'nightmares']})
```

Comment: `d = defaultdict(list)` is actually `d = defaultdict(lst)` if Iam not wrong, Thanks for your Answer

Comment: It should be  `d = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Got it, @Rakesh, now issue is in list I am getting same word multiple times, where can I apply set to remove duplicates? `d[k].extend(set(v))` is correct?

Comment: Because I want to get len of each abose, i.e. how many numbers of abuses are there in each list. I appreciate if you add code to use defaultdict and get length of each abuse type

Comment: `for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, set(v))` ?